# Vectorization of pcl_ros::transformPointCloud

Tags: c++, eigen, ros

I just noticed that the function [pcl_ros::transformPointCloud](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/indigo-devel/pcl_ros/src/transforms.cpp#L106) is not vectorized. Below is the code snippet copied from [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/indigo-devel/pcl_ros/src/transforms.cpp#L149).

```
void transformPointCloud(
    const Eigen::Matrix4f& transform, 
    const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& in,
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& out)
{
    int x_idx = pcl::getFieldIndex(in, "x");
    int y_idx = pcl::getFieldIndex(in, "y");
    int z_idx = pcl::getFieldIndex(in, "z");

    Eigen::Array4i xyz_offset(
        in.fields[x_idx].offset, 
        in.fields[y_idx].offset, 
        in.fields[z_idx].offset, 0);

    // most of the code is not shown here

    for (size_t i = 0; i < in.width * in.height; ++i)
    {
        Eigen::Vector4f pt(*(float*)&in.data[xyz_offset[0]], 
                           *(float*)&in.data[xyz_offset[1]],
                           *(float*)&in.data[xyz_offset[2]], 1);
        Eigen::Vector4f pt_out;
        pt_out = transform * pt;
    }

    memcpy(&out.data[xyz_offset[0]], &pt_out[0], sizeof(float));
    memcpy(&out.data[xyz_offset[1]], &pt_out[1], sizeof(float));
    memcpy(&out.data[xyz_offset[2]], &pt_out[2], sizeof(float));

    xyz_offset += in.point_step;
}
```

The code above iterated over each point in the point cloud and multiply the transformation with it.

**I am wondering if this can be vectorized so as to minimize the elapsed time.**

I am looking for suggestions to implement/incorporate the same. I am using ROS Indigo (PCL 1.7.1) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC.

Comment: If I mock the types that I don't know, the compiler will automatically vectorize this for you: https://godbolt.org/g/3hkWmP

Comment: @hlt Yes, this happens due to manual vectorization by Eigen, however. The compiler would not be allowed to re-arrange a 'trivial' matrix-vector-product implementation. Not sure what RaviJoshi means by "is not vectorized" ...

Comment: Interesting! Well, `transform` is an Eigen matrix. If we can convert the input point cloud to Eigen matrix, then we can simply write `transform * in` in one line in Eigen is going to take care of it. This is what I meant by saying vectorization. However, I think converting point cloud to an Eigen matrix would again took some time. In the end, my aim is to minimize the elapsed time of `transformPointCloud` function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `x_idx`, `y_idx`, and `z_idx` are `0`, `4` and `8` and you don't care about all the special case handling of non-finite data, etc, you can simplify the inner loop to something like this:

```
void foo(char* data_out, Eigen::Index N, int out_step, const Eigen::Matrix4f& T, const char* data_in, int in_step)
{
    for(Eigen::Index i=0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        Eigen::Vector3f::Map((float*)(data_out + i*out_step)).noalias()
          = (T * Eigen::Vector3f::Map((const float*)(data_in + i*in_step)).homogeneous()).head<3>();
    }
}
```

`N` would be `in.width * in.height` and `out_step` and `in_step` would be the corresponding `point_step` members. Minor possible improvement: You can copy `T` into a local variable so it does not need to be loaded from memory every time.

If `point_step` is a multiple of `sizeof(float)` you could also reduce this to a single assignment, using `out_stride = out.point_step / sizeof(float)`, etc. However, this usually generates less efficient code than the version above (may change in future versions of Eigen).

```
void foo2(float* data_out, Eigen::Index N, int out_stride, const Eigen::Matrix4f& T, const float* data_in, int in_stride)
{
    Eigen::Matrix3Xf::Map(data_out, 3, N, Eigen::OuterStride<>(out_stride)).noalias()
     = (T * 
        Eigen::Matrix3Xf::Map(data_in, 3, N, Eigen::OuterStride<>(in_stride))
            .colwise().homogeneous()
       ).topRows<3>();
}
```

[Godbolt-Link](https://godbolt.org/g/VWb9K3)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I haven't tested your suggestion yet. I have following two points to say: (1) I printed out some variables. ids `x_idx: 0, y_idx: 1, z_idx: 2`. members of `Eigen::Array4i xyz_offset` during initialization, i.e., `xyz_offset[0]: 0, xyz_offset[1]: 4, xyz_offset[2]: 8`. `point_step:32` is same for `in` and `out` cloud. (2) The variable `in.data` and `out.data` are `uint8[]` derived from [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html)

Comment: I just implemented your suggestion. Unfortunately, it is throwing **segmentation fault** at runtime. Please see the code snippet [here](https://pastebin.com/rjVi0re2). I am debugging it using `gdb`. It says following:
`Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`
`0x0000000000406a70 in Eigen::internal::gemm_pack_rhs<float, long, 4, 0, false, false>::operator()(float*, float const*, long, long, long, long, long) [clone .constprop.525] ()`
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: I also tried your first suggestion but got **segmentation fault** again. Please see the code snippet [here](https://pastebin.com/zGgMFDDY). Please note that I was getting `‘Index’ is not a member of ‘Eigen’` error with `Eigen::Index`, so I used `size_t` instead of `Eigen::Index`. I am using `eigen3` which is shipped along with ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit PC. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Replace `(float*)&out.data` by `out.data`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just realized that the `data` inside `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` is a `vector`. Hence, in the first method, i.e., `foo`, I changed `data_out` and `data_in` by `&out.data[0]` and  `&in.data[0]` respectively. It worked! However, you mentioned `foo2` when `point_step` is a multiple of `sizeof(float)`. In my case, `point_step` is `32`.  The function `foo2` now shows compilation errors. Please see [first version](https://pastebin.com/3jVk6yfQ) and [second versions](https://pastebin.com/tRdtdkPs).

Comment: In the second version you also need to write `(float*)(&out.data[0])` of course.

Comment: As always, thank you very much. I did a benchmarking of these two methods together with original implementation. Here are the results of benchmarking- `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud took ms: 4, foo took ms: 5, and foo2 took ms: 7`. You can see the complete code [here](https://pastebin.com/fE7AY3xk).